# NSInvalidArgumentException - setAllHTTPHeaderFields

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

New to iOS app programming. There's probably an easy fix, but I apparently don't know it. The following is the code in question:

```
NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
[theRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
```

And this is the exception being thrown:

```
[NSURLRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d82a7e0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: Also throws exception for addValue:forHTTPHeaderField

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to use an NSMutableURLRequest instead of an NSURLRequest.

Comment: I have used NSMutableURLRequest, but it throws this exception while running on my iPhone

Comment: Solved the issue, I forgot to change to NSMutableURLRequest both times I typed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error using `setAllHTTPHeaderFields`:
In my case,  I was sending non `NSString` parameters in the Dictionary.